# wamp and iis seperate application on same server

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, wamp

i have a VM where one website is on Wamp server port is 80, which i want to keep as default, i am making another application in different framework , which will be hosted on IIS on same VM, but with port 82, this application will have only 1 page, so my default site will be www.example.com (this will open Wamp server webpage), but www.example.com/iispage (this should open web application from IIS port 82).

right now www.example.com:82/iispage , opens the IIS page, but i dont want to show port, i need friendly url. Any advise.

Thank You

Comment: I don't think you can have two separate services (IIS and apache) listening on the same port. How would the O/S know which service to allow to process the incoming data? Remember we're not talking HTTP at this point, so there's no URL by which to distinguish, we're talking about a TCP /IP connection to a specific socket.

Comment: maybe you can change a hostname like aa.com

Answer (score 2):

Port 80 is the default web server port number, so we never normally use it on a URL.

If you want to address the IIS server on port 82, then on the url you give to the browser you have to add the port number as well

So you will have to do this

```
www.example.com:82/iispage
```